# Linux: additional default base security settings for working on the internet

Tags: linux, security

Can you provide additional default base security settings for working on the internet (not install software like fail2ban ...)?

I know is need to have these is important to do:

1. SELinux - set on Linux, kernel or system to Enforcing;
2. disable virtual consoles tty;
3. change message from /etc/issue and /etc/issue.net
4. get the ports with *netstat -tunlp* or *lsof -Pnl +M -i4* and set minimal;
5. set iptables rules;
6. set sudo permissions for default user;
7. disable root login for ssh in sshd_conf with: PermitRootLogin no;
8. change the default ssh port for connection;

Answer (score 0):

While these are useful steps, they are not really going to make your computer more secure for working on the Internet -- except maybe #8. When using the Internet, the application with the largest attack surface on your system is going to be the web browser, so securing your browser (and not so much the underlying OS) will provide most meaningful improvement in your security posture. That, and following basic Internet security hygiene.

Answer (score 0):

In no particular order

1. Think before you type
2. Keep your server updated. Install your distributions  security updates and bug fixes.
3. Don’t install (or remove) any services and software you don’t need.
4. Make backups and test your restore procedures
5. Don’t trust the advice / blogs / posts from random strangers on the internet (unless you understand what they try to tell you)
6. Much more than fits in the Q&A format

On mobile now but this touches on much of what I would recommend 
https://github.com/trimstray/the-practical-linux-hardening-guide/blob/master/README.md